# OpenGL Draw call on SLI/CrossFire Graphic Cards

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, sli

I am using OpenGL and OpenCL in my project. So, they are inter operating with each other. I have created some openGL buffers and fill them using OpenCL but when I am doing that with OpenCL, each GPU should have one context and two GPUs cannot be in one context even if they are in the same platform. Otherwise, I cannot create a GL Context and I will always have problem in context creation.

Now, I have one context per each GPU and some buffers exists on one GPU and the others exist on the other one. I want to render each buffer on the same GPU that it exist because otherwise the data will be transferred to the other GPU and it will decrease the performance. Anybody has any idea on how to render each buffer on the same GPU it exist?

Normally we just create  a gl context and then it will divide the tasks on the gpus. we don't have any mechanism to divide the task on different gpus.